# How to restore the correct fonts for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, fonts

After I tried FontExplorer X Pro, all the fonts across my system are displaying incorrectly (as shown below). How can I correct the fonts to display Chinese again?

[image: Screen shot from iTunes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reset fonts to their default settings in Windows 7:

- Open the **Control Panel** and go to:
  `Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Fonts\Font settings`
- **Click** `Restore default font settings`.
- **Click** `OK`.

  [image: Font settings]

Comment: thx. but I have tried this 4 hours ago, but it did work.

Comment: @Jichao Are all the fonts on your system not displaying properly? Or only certain applications?

Comment: All the programs and windows 7 itself not displaying chinese glyphs properly at least and the system could displaying english but the font is really strangle and complete different from before.

Comment: @Jichao Which edition of Windows 7 do you have? I think you may have to reinstall your language pack. Try installing one from here: [http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/languages](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/languages)

Answer (score 0):

That is a reasonable solution if you had the proper font installed. But when all you
see is the jumble up shapes it really becomes difficult to navigate the interface.
These commands my be somehow done through terminal otherwise you are wasting your time.

Daniel

Comment: It looks like you're responding to a [previous answer](https://superuser.com/questions/364895/how-to-restore-the-correct-fonts-for-windows-7/364901#364901) instead of posting a new answer. If so you can remove this answer and click 'add a comment' under that answer.